# API endpoint for getting user's Skype ID

Tags: skype, botframework

For our app I need to find user's Skype ID to connect user in our app with user in Microsoft Bot Framework.

I would like to know Is there any endpoint where I can get Skype ID? I can't find it. I guess the enpoint exists because ifttt.com while using Skype needs connect to my Microsoft account and uses skype.basic scope which is used for getting Skype ID.

I want to get ID like this:

```
29:1LJQ9JzcpZTXR6ArgCdwtivsGkVjO4rxbDUR_1hdsdf1
```

Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Messages from a user come through with the channelAccount record, which has a Skype ID in it.  It's somewhat anonymized for the bot, but it's durable for that particular bot.

Are you looking for some other id?